# Automapper causing stack overflow

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am using `Automapper` to map two classes:

```
public partial class db_MyObject
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public MyObject Parent { get; set; } // Parent can be null
}
```

How can I configure this mapping. I tried this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<db_MyObject, MyObject>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Parent, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(model => new db_MyObject() { 
           Id = model.ParentId ?? 0 }));
```

and it caused stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
Mapper.CreateMap<db_MyObject, MyObject>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Parent,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing(model => new MyObject() { 
            Id = model.ParentId ?? 0 })
    );
```

I.e. `new MyObject()` instead of `new db_MyObject()`, because `Parent` is a `MyObject`?

Comment: How can I create the mapping so that when ParentId is null, Parent is also null (not a new MyObject with ID = 0), and when ParentId is not null, then a new MyObject with that ID?

Comment: `opt => opt.ResolveUsing(model => model.ParentId.HasValue ? new MyObject() { Id = model.ParentId.Value } : null)`. This uses the ternary operator: `<condition> ? <then value> : <else value>`.

Comment: See: [?: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)